# Do we want specific hash tags for automatic Tweets

Tags: discussion

The SE Twitter Bot will send out an tweet from [@StackDrupal](https://twitter.com/StackDrupal) [every few hours based on a magic algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work).

Right now, the tweet will get the hashtag for the most popular tag on the post.  Very often, it is something meaningless for this site, like #views, #images, or #fields.

There is a [proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/add-site-specific-hashtag-to-twitter-feeds) on the Meta StackExchange site to allow per-site hashtags.

Do we want our own hashtag?  What should it be?

Comment: Personally, I think everything from @StackDrupal should have the #drupal hashtag.

Comment: FYI: current support for this forces the tag you choose to *override* any tag that might be applied based on the question tags. Sometimes, this makes sense: if the automatic tags are pretty generic, they're not really adding much context. But... It's all or nothing, so...

Comment: @Shog9 Looking at `@StackDrupal` with its #images and #fields, I'd say #drupal *probably* makes more sense.

Comment: I think #drupal is a bit too spammy and general, and I would probably block @StackDrupal on twitter so I wouldn't see it.

Comment: @mradcliffe – Why would you consider this spammy? Posting something about Drupal and adding `#Drupal` doesn't seem a bit spammy I think. It seems as if a hash**tag** is actually used as intended.

Comment: I would prefer not to get questions/answers spammed at me on twitter as I follow #Drupal since I prefer organic tweets by humans rather than curated content by bots. However it should be pretty easy to just block @StackDrupal so it's probably not a problem. I'll probably do that.

Answer (score 1):

Searched exactly that question!

Yes, there should always be at least this one hashtag:

[`#Drupal`](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Drupal)

By that we may raise the probability to get spoiled into the timelines of those people this whole site is relevant for. Without the `#Drupal` hashtag these tweets most likely will just run through without anybody noticing them. As `#Drupal` already is a widely accepted hashtag, we should go for it.

Look at the screenshot below. This tweet got tagged `#blocks`. But who on Twitter to reach with that tag? It's an in-site relevant tag. But outside of Drupal Answers this tag does have zero relevance. If it at least would have been `#react` that would be different. All tweets from here really must use `#Drupal` as this is what this tweet in a broader context is about. Upvote if you agree.

[image]